# How to calculate a confidence interval for a trimmed mean

Tags: confidence-interval, trimmed-mean

I try to get the sample size that presents the population, I averaged randomly the 10 and then the 20 readings then  I used the formula CI = 1.96 * std/root n, that gave me the CI at any (n),  but how can I get the CI if the (n) has been excluded the high and low value at say 10 or 20 readings?

Comment: The trimmed mean is not a parameter of a distribution, so the question arises: what are you trying to estimate with it?  If you are using it to estimate the mean (which may be questionable, because the trimmed mean could be a heavily biased estimator of the mean), then your question is "how do I obtain a confidence interval for the *mean*."  The answer to that might depend on why you are trimming.  Presumably that's because you are concerned about influential outliers: but do you have any particular expectations about the frequency and magnitudes of those outliers?

Comment: Yaser -- If you are trimming in order to estimate a population mean, how are you estimating the standard deviation? Much about your post needs to be made explicit. What you're attempting to achieve (and why), and exactly what calculations you're doing (and why) might all be important. As whuber has already indicated, a CI is an interval for a population quantity, not a sample statistic, so you need to be clear what population quantity you're trying to produce an interval for and under what assumptions.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying. I am using hardness tester on rock sample  and try to know that how many impacts (readings) I would need to get a sample mean which is almost equal to the population mean, based on 100 readings.From this population data set, a subset number of readings (e.g., 10, 15, 20, 30) were randomly selected,  and the mean value was determined with CI degree.

Comment: @whuber I try to determine the minimum number of readings required to carry out a 'Valid' test. In the case above it  was easy  to get CI for these number of readings by using the formal of CI=1.96 * sd/root(n),  but when I tried to exclude the high and low value of say 10 or 20 readings, it gave me a closer sample mean than those that including high and low value. Know  , how can I get the CI for these readings.

Comment: You may want to look at the book "Introduction to Robust Estimation and Hypothesis Testing", by Rand Wilcox. You are probably interested in estimating the population trimmed mean $\mu_t$; formulas and R functions for constructing confidence intervals for this parameter, based on the sample trimmed mean, are described in Chapter 4.

Comment: @BrentKerby Thank you. I have never used R, Does the Excel have the function that can calculate the CI of trimmed mean?

Comment: @YaserFalgy, I'm not aware of such a function in Excel. But R is available for free download, and there are plenty of tutorials online, which should make it not too hard to get started with. Alternatively, you could implement the formulas manually in Excel.

Comment: @whuber: The trimmed mean is indeed not a parameter, but its expectation is (if it exists).

Comment: @Michael I believe there may be a subtle problem with your claim.  We should be concerned that the expectation of the trimmed mean might depend on the sample size. In fact it will when the underlying distribution is not symmetric.  Thus (in general) *its expectation is not a property of the distribution itself.*  My original question stands: exactly what property of that distribution is the trimmed mean intended to estimate? (Brent Kerby proposed a reasonable one--but notice that it is not the mean.)

Comment: Thx for clarification @whuber. The book of Wilcox is on my "wishlist" since some months!

Comment: Thank you all for detailed answer.   my rocks are sandstone which is uniform rock with SD=20 and shows normal distribution. I will look at the formula of CI for trimmed mean In the Wilcox book.